# Prove the sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1-e^{-x_n}}-a$ for $(0<a<1)$ converges to the root of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I encountered a elementary problem in a small calculus competition from local college. After a little study, yet I find it seems not that obvious to solve.

Given the sequence defined as
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1-e^{-x_n}}-a,\quad(0<a<1)$$
with $x_1=1-a$, prove its convergence and find the limit.

(Here I think the initial item $x_1$ may not important to the convergence or the limit, let $x_1=1-a$ is only for students to simplify their answer in such a test, a general proof may not need the value of $x_1$.)

Some simple attempt:

If the sequence converges, it is not difficult to find the limit is the root of function $f(x)$, which is
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{e^x-1}=a$$
and easy to show $f(x)$ is monotonic to $(0,1)$, which guarantees $f(x)=a$ always has the only root, as well the limit of sequence, denoting $x_0$.

A straight idea is the prove the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically increasing to their upper-bound $x_0$. (But it is only a guess, maybe my idea is wrong from the beginning).

To utilize induction, it is easy to check $1-a=x_1<x_2<x_0$. Now given $1-a=x_1<x_{n-1}<x_n<x_0$, the problem can be solved if we can prove $1-a=x_1<x_n<x_{n+1}<x_0$. The monotonicity $x_n<x_{n+1}$ is also easy to check if we already have $x_n<x_0$, however, $x_{n+1}<x_0$ is not that obvious to prove.

Maybe such simple idea is just not the right approach, so I am waiting for some further suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your idea is right. Your problem is how to prove that $x_n<x_0$. To see this, we shall use induction. Suppose we have $x_n<x_0$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=\frac{x_n}{1-e^{-x_n}}-a\\
&=e^{x_n}\frac{x_n}{e^{x_n}-1}-a\\
&<e^{x_0}\frac{x_0}{e^{x_0}-1}-a\\
&=\left(\frac{x_0}{a}+1\right)a-a\\
&=x_0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh. Thanks! Seems just one last step I was missing it.